# non-helper << operator not working C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the `<< operator` for the display function call.
Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
// global variable
const int MAX = 3;

// class definition 
class CString{
    char str[MAX+1];
public:
    CString(char* param){
       if(param == nullptr){
       str[0] = '\0';
       return;
       }
       strncpy(str,param,MAX);
       str[MAX] = '\0';
    }
    void display(ostream& os){
       os << str;
    }
};

// << operator overloading 
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, CString& cs){
    static int call = 0;
    os << call << ": ";
    cs.display(os);
    call++;
    return os;
}

void process(char* parm){
    CString cs(parm);
    // here is where my issue is
    cs.display(cout);
    cout << endl;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    cout << "Command Liine : ";
    for(int arg = 0; arg < argc ; arg++){
        cout << " " << argv[arg];
    }
    cout << endl;
    if( argc == 1){
        cout << "Insufffiecentnumber of arguemnts (min1)" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << " Maxium numver of characters stored: " << MAX << endl;
    for(int arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++){
        process(argv[arg]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: 
Here is the correct output and the output I have:

```
  Correct:
    Command Line : w1 oop345 btp305
    Maximum number of characters stored : 3
    0: oop
    1: btp
  Mine:
    Command Line : w1 OOP345 DBS305
    Maxium number of characters stored: 3
    OOP
    DBS
```

I'm having an issue with my `<< operator` not working, I can't seem to figure it out. The `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CString& cs)` does not seem to be loading its syntax.

Question:

Does anyone know where my mistake has been made?

Comment: Please include an example input and output; for me, it seems your  code is working (except I had to switch nullptr with NULL to compile it).

Comment: @Paul92 just edited the post! with the correct output and the output I'm receiving

Comment: I highly recommend renaming your string class, as `CString` is often used by [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx).  Maybe pick a different prefix letter like UString or HString.

Comment: I also recommend using `std::string` instead of writing your own.  The `std::string` facilities have already been debugged, so you don't have to waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a correct overloading of `<< operator`, but in method `process()` you used a public method `display()` of class `CString` instead of using `<< operator` directly.

Just change one line in method `process()`:

`cs.display(cout);` to: `cout << cs;`

```
void process(char* parm){
    CString cs(parm);
    // here is where my issue is
    cout << cs;
    cout << endl;
}
```

P.S. you do not need method `CString::display` at all as you already overload `<< operator` for this class.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why this appears to fix the problem.